# Can I take parental leave if I worked for 12 months with blue card in Germany?

Tags: visa, germany, working-visas, blue-card, work-permit

I have been working in Germany with my blue card for 6 months now. I am pregnant and my due date is beginning of June 2024. I will have 12 months working on May 15th 2024. So, am I eligible to take parental leave and parental money? Thank you

Comment: This [Parental Allowance and Parental Leave](https://www.bmfsfj.de/resource/blob/139908/72ce4ea769417a058aa68d9151dd6fd3/elterngeld-elterngeldplus-englisch-data.pdf) might be of interest (I will leave it to others with better knowledge to answer definitively)